# XLS export as XML causes unknown data conversion

Tags: xml, csv, date, xls, file-conversion

I exported an `.xls` file using Gnumeric 1.12.28 to `.xml` (and also `.csv`) and the output is fine for the most part, but dates are converted in a way I can not decode.

For example, the date `20.07.1953` (given as `dd.mm.yyyy`) becomes `19560`. It does not matter, how the cell is formatted within Gnumeric, I tried several options. While the `.csv` file does not contain any further information, the related line in the `.xml` file looks like`<gnm:Cell Row="8" Col="9" ValueType="40" ValueFormat="[$-f8f2]m/d/yy">19560</gnm:Cell>`. Sometimes, the `ValueFormat` part is also missing. It is definetely not a valid Unix epoch timestamp (seconds since 01.01.1970), however.

I googled `ValueFormat="[$-f8f2]m/d/yy"` but the results were just very few and not useful. I think that the date value is not correctly interpreted during export, or that I get just the internal representation of this value.

Anyone any idea how to decode the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnumeric/stable/quick-format.html.en):

> Usually, the value Gnumeric uses for dates is the number of days since January 1st, 1900

Also see remark.